# Page does not refresh even after redirecting from backend

Tags: node.js, express

I have a post request for my web app for sign up page and I want to render the page to the front end, my sign up page looks like this:

```
const CustomAPIError = require('../../errors/customError')
//import jsonwebtoken for using jwt to issue token from the server to send secret to the user
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config()


const login = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ msg: 'logged in' })
}

const createsignupuser = async (req, res) => {
  const { Firstname, Lastname, Email, password, confirmPassword, username } = req.body
  if (!Firstname || !Lastname || !Email || !password || !confirmPassword || !username) {
    throw new Error("please provide appropriate credentials", 400)
  }

  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    throw new Error('password does not match')
  }

  return res.status(200).redirect('/login')
}




module.exports = { createsignupuser, login }
```

and  even though its redirecting on the network tab it is not redirecting on the actual page, could someone please help me.

Comment: try `return res.redirect('/login')`

Comment: Can you show login route?

Comment: ```return res.redirect('/login")``` did not work and the login route is the function called login(see code above)

Comment: You are redirecting to log in right? but it is sending a JSON response. Check it out.

Comment: no, on the network tab on the response section it was returning the actual login page without redirecting the actual page(the whole website) but I have used fetch to refresh the page

Comment: can you take out "return" keyword? Just say  `res.status(200).redirect('/login')`

Comment: I did and it didn't work... I used the refactored code on the solutions below

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to solve this error

```
fetch(req).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  response.json().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).